# UI Design to Select Multiple files and their associated files in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I have a scenario where user needs to select multiple files and for each selected file he may or may not choose additional file path that need to be mapped .

For example lets say we have a folder which contains 7 files File1,File2,File3 AssociatedFile1,AssociatedFile2, associatedFile3,AssociatedFile4.

My UI should be such that Once I Select File1 I should now be able to select Associated Files which can be 0 to n and then go back in selecting the second file and this repeats till user finishes selecting the required number of files. Finally I need  a map of files and their respective associate files

Any QT design Ideas for this or sample applications to refer

Comment: What's wrong with [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html)?